# Need to implement magento 2 tax based on product amount

Tags: magento2, product, price, tax

I am trying to implement **tax on products**. There are conditions as follow.

1. If product amount is **less than 1000 Rs** then tax should be **5%**
2. if product amount is **greater than 1000 Rs** then tax should be **12%**

Is there already any functionality i can configure in **magento 2** or do i need a custom solution for it.

For custom solution please guide me also with some reference links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: You will need to create two tax rates**

```
(1) Rate-5
(2) Rate-10
```

**Step 2: Create two product class:**

```
Taxes > Tax Rules > Add New Tax Rule > Additional Settings > Add New Product Tax Class

(1) Product-Tax-Class-5
(2) Product-Tax-Class-10
```

**Step 3: Create two tax rule:**

```
(1) Tax-Rule-5

 - Tax Rate: Rate-5
 - Product Tax Class: Product-Tax-Class-5

(2) Tax-Rule-10

 - Tax Rate: Rate-10
 - Product Tax Class: Product-Tax-Class-10
```

**Step 4: Assign Tax Class of Products:**

```
(1) If Product price is less than 1000 : Product-Tax-Class-5

(2) If Product price is greater than 1000 : Product-Tax-Class-10
```

Comment: Although it will solve my problem,but this process is manual, do we have any way to automate this ?